# Bitcoins recently sent from localbitcoins.com wallet not showing in recipient wallet

Tags: wallet-recovery

I recently sent bitcoin from local bitcoin .com and it's not registering in my wallet that I sent it. It's 1000$ what do I do?

Comment: Please provide more details. You say it's not registering in your wallet, what client are you using? Do you have a transaction ID?

Comment: Ok I have no idea what a transaction i.d. is  but please help. I sent the bitcoins from localbitcoins.com. I copied the bitcoin address that was provided from my bitcoin wallet n pasted it on local bitcoins.com sent the coins to that address and their not showing up in my wallet and it's been almost 24 hours and I'm getting really worried because it never took this long. And theirs no way for me to see what's going on.

Comment: And also the bitcoin address in my wallet changed so doesn't that mean the coins are coming thourgh?

Comment: I'm able to see on local bitcoins.com the transaction I made n what address I sent it too but the coins never got received into my wallet

Comment: It is quite clear what the OP is asking, just that not many details which would better enable experienced users to assist have been provided.

Comment: He still hasn't stated what wallet client he is using. He could be using a full node client and it's just syncing, but we have no idea since OP isn't providing enough details.

Answer (score 1):

I do not use localbitcoins.com but it is possible if you can see the transaction that you made, you might be able to find the transaction ID. Then, you can search for your transaction ID on blockchain.info to find out the status. Even if you cannot, the answer is just to wait.

Every time you request a receiving address a new one is generated.